# Folding a box with bones

Tags: animation, rigging

Can anyone help me with this simple rigging animation. I want to fold a piece, but my bones would not stick to the edges, what do I wrong? I am very new to blender.

I'll explain the problem from the beginning:

I would like to make an animation of a display. I am very new to Blender, so I have to learn a lot. To start I would like to make one part of the whole display. It is a tray.

[image]

I exported this from Illustrator as a SVG file. When I import this in Blender and tried to make a mesh of it, but it will not be a flat part.

[image]

How can I solve this problem first? After that I have to extrude it and use shift K to make the dieline? And add bones to make it move?

Do you recommend this way?

I've added the Blender file with the imported SVG file.

[image]

Comment: Hi. You need to explain your problem, if you wish to get good answers. The better you explain, what is it that you are struggling with, the better the answers. Pictures and screenshots would also be usefull.

Comment: Hi, you are right! I'll make a better explanation with pictures in a moment!

Comment: Sarah, from what you write I get the feeling that you are completely new to Blender. There is nothing wrong with being new, but I am afraid you will not be able to skip the learning part if you wish to use Blender. I would suggest starting with at least some basic modelling tutorials on YouTube. You will need to learn how to create your model first, rigging will be the next step after that, however, you may not necessarily need a rig for simple animations not involving organic deformations.